# Как объединить два массива подмассива если первые элементы одинаковые?

Tags: ruby

У меня есть такого рода массив:

```
[[20680, 31135], [20680, 31136], [20681, 31137], 
[20682, 31138], [20682, 31139], [20683, 31140], [20683, 31141], 
[20684, 31142], [20685, 31143], [20685, 31144]]
```

Мне нужно получить вот такой:

```
[[31135, 31136], [31137], 
 [31138, 31139], [31140, 31141] и.т.д....
```

или вот такой хэш:

```
["20680" => [31135, 31136], "20681" => [31137], 
 "20682" => [31138, 31139], "20683" => [31140, 31141] и.т.д....
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

```
a = [[1, 2], ...]
a.inject({}) { |hash, arr|
  hash[arr[0]] = hash.fetch(arr[0], []).push(arr[1])
  hash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Массив можно "нарезать" с помощью `slice_when` на местах, где первые элементы отличаются:

```
arr.slice_when { |a, b| a.first != b.first }.to_a
# этот перечислитель ленивый, поэтому нужно ^^^^^, чтобы посмотреть на данные
# => [[[20680, 31135], [20680, 31136]],
#     [[20681, 31137]],
#     [[20682, 31138], [20682, 31139]],
#     [[20683, 31140], [20683, 31141]],
#     [[20684, 31142]],
#     [[20685, 31143], [20685, 31144]]]
```

Теперь от каждой пары в каждом подмассиве надо получить только первый её элемент:

```
arr.slice_when { |a, b| a.first != b.first }.map { |e| e.map(&:first) }
#                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# => [[20680, 20680], [20681], [20682, 20682], [20683, 20683], [20684], [20685, 20685]]
```

Однако одинаковые первые элементы, не идущие в массиве подряд, при таком обходе попадут в разные группы.

---

Если же одинаковые первые элементы, идущие **не подряд**, должны будут оказаться в одной группе, сгодится и хэшмап, поможет `group_by`:

```
arr.group_by(&:first)
# => {20680=>[[20680, 31135], [20680, 31136]],
#     20681=>[[20681, 31137]],
#     20682=>[[20682, 31138], [20682, 31139]],
#     20683=>[[20683, 31140], [20683, 31141]],
#     20684=>[[20684, 31142]],
#     20685=>[[20685, 31143], [20685, 31144]]}
```

К сожалению, для хэшмапа нет "мгновенного" способа преобразовать каждое значение, поэтому придётся использовать промежуточную переменную (ну, или `tap`):

```
grouped = arr.group_by(&:first)
grouped.each_pair { |k, v| grouped[k] = v.map(&:first) }
# => {20680=>[20680, 20680],
#     20681=>[20681],
#     20682=>[20682, 20682],
#     20683=>[20683, 20683],
#     20684=>[20684],
#     20685=>[20685, 20685]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) из Ruby 2.4:

```
.group_by(&:first).transform_values{ |g| g.map(&:last) }
```